# How to add sub books in table of content?

Tags: table-of-contents, books

I am writing a book (documentclass: book) that has sub-books like Book 1, Book 2 etc.
Currently to add the Book 1 as a new page , I am doing the following :

```
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\huge Book I : 

\huge Is this company healthy ?
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\end{center}
\newpage
```

However, how do I add this into my table of contents such that the chapters in book 1 comes under it.
A short visualization of what I want

```
Contents 

Preface...............................................1
Book 1
    Chapter 1.........................................2
```

How do I achieve this ?
Am I using a wrong document class ? I am not sure if it is called sub book or something else.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using [`book`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co)'s `\part`, reformatted as `\book`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\partname}{Book}
\newcommand{\book}{\part}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
\sloppy\lipsum[1]

\book{First book}

\chapter{First chapter}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{First section}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[1-50]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

Formatting of the ToC can be achieved using [`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft), and one ca also adjust the formatting of `\part`/`\book` if needed.

Comment: I will try this and get back to you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the `memoir` class, which has a `book` document division. I've grabbed some of @Werner's code below).

```
% subbookprob.tex  SE 572544

\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%\renewcommand{\partname}{Book}
%\newcommand{\book}{\part}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
\sloppy\lipsum[1]

\counterwithout*{chapter}{book} % make chapternumbers start anew in each book

\book{First book}

\chapter{First chapter}\lipsum[1]
\section{First section}\lipsum[1]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[1]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[1]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[1]

\book{Second book}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}

\chapter{First chapter}\lipsum[1]%-50]
\section{First section}\lipsum[1]%-50]

\end{document}
```

[image]